"Posts edited" and Copy Editor badge progress are inconsistent due to Staging Ground edits
I noticed that my "Copy Editor" badge progress and the "posts edited" numbers are different.

The former is 333 while the latter is 340. I thought these count the same things.
After some investigation, it appears that this is because my edits in the Staging Ground. Those count towards "posts edited", but not "Copy Editor", even after the post has graduated from SG.
Is this intentional?
